# surjective differentiable function 3

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, f has at least one zero, $f'(x)\neq 0$. Prove that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=x+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is surjective.

I've tried to prove the monotony

Comment: I think I can use also Darboux